# Extract only certain content of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Given the possible string combinations as below, how can I extract the content which is inside the 'abs()'?

```
mod(abs(5),3,8)     -> '5'
mod(abs((5)),abs(3),8)   -> '5' and '3'
mod(abs(5),(3),abs((8)))   -> '5' and '8'
```

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: SQL Server v14..

Comment: You'd be better off using a language that support REGEX. T-SQL does not. If you must do this in T-SQL, you'll doing to very likely need to invest in some REGEX CLR Functions.

Comment: yeah i wish i can do in front end but this is inside the trigger so must be in T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity primary key clustered,
colA varchar(100)
);

insert into @t(colA) 
values('mod(abs(5),3,8)'), ('mod(abs((5)),abs(3),8)'), ('mod(abs(5),(3),abs((8)))'),
('(in:A-1)(out:2-B)(abs(123))(mod(567))(out:X)(in:0)mod((((4))))(      22       )');

select t.*, ltrim(rtrim(stuff(ss.value, 1, len(ss.value+'.') - charindex('(', reverse(ss.value)), '')))
from @t as t
cross apply string_split(t.colA, ')') as ss
where rtrim(ss.value) like '%(%[0-9]'; --'%abs(%[0-9]';
```

Comment: how can I assign the output into a variable? is it possible to do it without using Select?

Comment: you can definitely assign the output to a variable, for eg. concatenate the rows/columns into a long string. the part of your question"..without using Select" is a bit confusing though.